# Bash multiple variable assignment

Tags: linux, bash, shell

## Objective

Assign HTTP status code and date from cURL output to `RESP` and `DATE` variables using one-liner command.

## Expectation

```
[08 Nov 2017 19:28:44 GMT] 301
```

## Reality

```
$ read -d "\n" RESP DATE <<< $(curl -sv https://google.com 2>&1 | egrep -i "< HTTP/2|< Date" | sed "s/< HTTP\/2 //;s/< date: //g"); echo "[$DATE] $RESP"
[
] 30108 Nov 2017 19:28:44 GMT
$
```

EDIT:

Here's the full working command:

```
$ read -d "\r" RESP DATE <<< $(curl -sv https://google.com 2>&1 | tr -d "\r" | egrep -i "< HTTP/2|< Date" | sed "s/< HTTP\/2 //;s/< date: //g"); echo "[$DATE] $RESP"
[Wed, 08 Nov 2017 19:57:33 GMT] 301
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `curl` contains some `\r` characters,
that's why the output looks messed up.
You can get rid of it by inserting a `tr -d '\r'` into the pipeline after the `curl` and before the `egrep`.

Is it really important to read into `RESP` and `DATE` variables?
You could use Awk to extract the interesting parts simpler, saner,
and output directly in the desired format:

```
curl ... | tr -d '\r' | awk '/^< Date: / { date = substr($0, 9); print "[" date "] " resp } /^< HTTP\// { resp = $3 }'
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now! I edited my post with full working command. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

How about awk:

```
curl --silent --head https://google.com | awk '
    /^HTTP/ {code = $2} 
    /^Date:/ {
        sub(/\r$/,"")
        date = substr($0,7)
        printf "[%s] %s\n", date, code
        exit
    }
'
```

Using an HTTP `HEAD` request to minimize traffic.